# Connecting to a DB2 database using Servlets

Tags: java, database, servlets, db2

Hey I'm trying to connect to a `DB2` database, by using `Servlets`(Using `NetBeans` right now) but I just can't find a useful example on the web, could someone help me?

Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's no different to connecting to a DB2 database *without* using a Servlet :)

A quick [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=db2%20jdbc) came up with [some documentation on using JDBC with DB2](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/ad/cjvjt2cn.htm). That page has some code examples that should get you started.

Essentially it's a matter of obtaining a `Connection` object using either the `DriverManager` or `DataSource` interfaces. Once you have that you can obtain `Statements` or `PreparedStatements` are you're good to go.

Comment: You'll want to consider using a connection pool rather than DriverManager if it's servlets.

Comment: @Duffymo makes a good point: if you're building a real-world system then you'll need a good connection pooling library, otherwise your system will have pretty bad latency. It's probably better to use a `DataSource` rather than `DriverManager`. `DataSource` is a better design and makes it much easier to transparently include things like connection pooling.

Comment: Everything else that Cameron said is spot on.